# Как найти 2 рядом стоящие нечётные цифры?

Tags: javascript

Пользователь должен ввести хаотичные цифры в `prompt("","")`, например, 84753198546.

Дальше нужен код, который найдёт `2` рядом стоящих нечётных цифры, в нашем случае (75-первая пара), и поставит между ними восклицательный знак ->(7!5)

В итоге должно получиться (847!5!3!1!98546).

Такое задание мне дали, и я без понятия как должен выглядеть этот код.

Comment: В чем проблема перебрать массив и сравнить элементы?

Comment: "Такое задание мне дали, и я без понятия" - значит Вам нужны более простые задания.

Comment: @xydope как мне преобразовать стринг из промпта в массив?

Comment: `(prompt("","") || "").split("")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое простое решение - регулярное выражение:

```js
result = prompt('Введите число:', 84753198546);
alert(result.replace(/\D/gim, '').replace(/([13579](?=[13579]))/gim, '$1!'));
```

---

Если Вам необходимо решение именно через массивы:

```js
// Получаем строку с числом
let str = prompt('Введите число:', '84753K198546');
// Создаём массив из цифр разбиванием строки,
// указав в качестве разделителя любые символы,
// которые не являются цифрами
let arr = str.split(/\D*/);
// Создаём результирующий массив
let arr2 = [];
/* Перебираем элементы исходного массива */
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // Заносим в результирующий массив
  // текущий элемент исходного массива
  arr2.push(arr[i]);
  // Если текущий и следующий элементы исходного массива
  // не имеют остатка при делении на 2, тогда...
  if (arr[i] % 2 != 0 && arr[i + 1] % 2 != 0) {
    // Добавляем в результирующий массив
    // необходимый разделитель
    arr2.push('!');
  }
}
// Выводим результирующий массив преобразовав его в строку
alert(arr2.join(''));
```

Или так:

```js
let str = prompt('Введите число:', '847531T98546');

let arr = str.split(/\D*/).map((c, i, a) => {
  return (c % 2 && a[i + 1] % 2) ? c + '!' : c;
}).join('');

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все хорошо работает. только к сожалению я не очень понимаю как это работает, ибо сейчас нахожусь на начальной стадии в JS. но все же спасибо.
я почти написал этот же код более понятным способом, но тут не хватает одной маленькой детали,       [
 let str = prompt('','');
let arr = str.split('');
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i]%2!=0 && arr[i+1]%2!=0){
        *******
    }
}   ]
я не помню какой метод используется для того чтобы добавить новый элемент после arr[i]. то есть чтобы добавить (!) в строку

Comment: @user396639: дополнил

Comment: Да, это то что нужно!  Спасибо огромное)